# Where else is anything to be prized above life to be found in the Old Testament?

Tags: bible, old-testament, love, psalms, divine-mercy

According to [Psalms 63:4](https://bible.usccb.org/bible/psalms/63) in the NAB:

> For your love is better than life; my lips shall ever praise you!

Now, according to the commentary contained therein: *For your love is better than life: only here in the Old Testament is anything prized above life--in this case God’s love.*

Does anyone know if this is gloss is true? That is, is there another instance in the Old Testament where something is considered to be *better than life*?

Because of some other (questionable) commentary I have seen in the NAB, I am skeptical; and so, I am posing this question.

Also, it seems that the words "love" and "mercy" may be interchangeable, as the word "mercy" is used in place of the word "love" in the Douay-Rheims Bible--Psalm 62 (Vulgate numbering).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Wisdom** The book of Proverbs places a high premium on *wisdom*:

> *Wisdom is more precious than rubies, and nothing you desires can compare with her.* (Proverbs 8:11)

> *For whoever finds me finds life, and receives favor from the Lord.* (Proverbs 8:35)

It was stated that the FIRST thing ever created was Wisdom, *before His deeds of old*. (8:22) So wisdom must be placed extremely high on the scale of priorities and values preceding LIFE.

Answer (score 0):

This verse comes close:

> Then I commended **mirth**, because a man hath **no better thing under
> the sun**, than to eat, and to drink, and to be merry: for that shall
> abide with him of his labour the days of his life, which God giveth
> him under the sun.  (Ecclesiastes 8:15, KJV)

And, so far as I can ascertain, there is none that comes nearer to answering this question.

Regarding the love-mercy issue, check the Hebrew: if the root for the word is "hesed" (*het, samed, dalet* root letters), as it is in Psalm 63:3(4) as quoted in the OP where it was translated as "love", then this word actually means much more than love.  Many translations use "lovingkindness."  The word implies faithfulness, continuance/constancy, mercy, love, compassion, and kindness--all wrapped up in one.  There is no good word in English for this.